# Laravel - relacionamento 1 para duas tabelas e ordenar

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho uma tabela de playlist, uma tabela de playlist_content e duas tabelas de VODContent e LiveContent.

Hoje faço a relação entre vodcontent e livecontent com um relacionamento hasManyThrough.
*$this->hasManyThrough(VODContent::class, PlaylistContent::class, 'playlist_id', 'content_id', 'id', 'content_id');*

Quando eu listo os conteudos da playlist, eu gostaria de ordenar em um campo de order que fica na tabela intermediaria, o playlist_content, só que se eu coloco order by em cada relacionamento (vod e live), quando eu faço o merge para exibir todos os conteudos da live, ai que gera o problema, ele vai pegar pela ordem, mas priorizando pelo merge.
Eu pensei no collection fazer um sort pelo order, mas ele não retorna o campo dessa coluna intermediaria, teria alguma forma de pegar a coluna da tabela intermediaria?

Tentando simplificar como que iria ser visualizado.
VOD tem conteudo na ordem 1, 3
e Live tem conteudo na ordem 2
Com o merge para exibir os resultados, se eu coloco o vod como primeiro e live em segundo, ele acaba retornando 1,3,2. O correto seria ordenar com 1,2,3 nesse exemplo.

**Relacionamentos no model Playlist**

```
public function live_contents() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(LiveContent::class, PlaylistContent::class, 'playlist_id', 'content_id', 'id', 'content_id')->orderBy("order");
}

public function vod_contents() {    
  return $this->hasManyThrough(VODContent::class, PlaylistContent::class, 'playlist_id', 'content_id', 'id', 'content_id')->orderBy("order"); 
}
```

**Para a listagem dos conteudos com merge**

```
$contents = new Collection($playlist->vod_contents()->paginate());
$livecontents = new Collection($playlist->live_contents()->paginate());
$collection = $contents->merge($livecontents);
return collect($collection);
```

Comment: Sua modelagem me parece estranha, você tem duas tabelas de contents quando poderia ter somente uma e indicar uma flag content_type.

Quanto a este código vejo que você deu merge em duas collections paginadas, o resultado não será os dados duas collections com uma nova paginação e sim as duas paginações juntas.

Eu talvez eu não tenha lido direito.

Comment: Sim, ainda estou pensando melhorar essa modelagem, em breve juntando a tabela de vodcontents e livecontents (que ambos também tem o content type para fazer outra diferenciação). Enfim, eu acho que no lugar de paginate é get mesmo, talvez tenha copiado de algum teste.

Answer (score 0):

Cara faz da seguinte forma esse relacionamento que da certo:

No model playlist:

```
public function live_contents() {

   return $this->hasMany(LiveContent::class, 'playlist_id', 'id')->orderBy('order', 'DESC'); //Você escolhe a ordem, ASC ou DESC

}

public function vod_contents() {

  return $this->hasMany(VodContent::class, 'playlist_id', 'id')->orderBy('order','ASC') //Você escolhe a ordem, ASC ou DESC
}
```

No controller:

```
$playlists = Playlist::with('live_contents', 'vod_contents')->paginate(10);
```

Na view:

```
@foreach($playlists as $playlist)
     {{dd($playlist->live_contents, $playlist->vod_contents)}}
@endforeach
```

Só testar e ser feliz